# Meta Flair #fail

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, flair

There seems to be a problem with user flair for meta.

I have implemented the JavaScript versions to display my flair for Stackoverflow and Meta.Stackoverflow.  The flair for meta doesn't display the icon.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source, it does seem like a bug. The Meta flair is using a **relative link**, which cannot work on other sites.

Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7586.html

```
<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7586.html

```
<img src="/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 7):

This will be resolved after we deploy tonight.